# C program to print a series

Tags: c, loops, series

I am writing a program in C to print following series.

```
   1
  121
 12321
1234321
```

Below is my code which works perfectly fine but is there any change which i can make to make the program use less loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int num, i, j, terms, x;
printf("ENTER NUMBER OF TERMS: ");
scanf("%d", &terms);
x = terms--;
for(num=1;num<=terms;num++){
    for(i=1;i<=x;i++){
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(i=1; i<=num; i++) {
        printf("%d", i);
    }
    for(j=num-1 ; j>0; j--){
        printf("%d", j);
     }
    printf("\n");
    x--;
   }
}
```

Comment: If your code works (a hard requirement) and you want a review of the code to possibly improve it, then please post on [the Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Comment: Please explain why you want fewer loops. There are several different ways to achieve that. But meta-reasons would reject some of them. For example I somehow feel that using recursion and specific printf-features would not be appreciated by a teacher of a programming class which did not discuss them yet, even if the code then can have zero loops (which I bet is easily possible). Also, the code gets much harder read then. So please take one logical step back and describe what you want to achieve by reducing the number of loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can fusion the two first loops making an if else statement and using de answer below to print x spaces with one single print

for(i=1;i<=x;i++){
    printf(" ");
}
for(i=1; i<=num; i++) {
    printf("%d", i);
}



printf("%*c", n+1, '1');
for(i=1; i<=num; i++) {
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

or specify the number of spaces like the answer below, deleting the first loop

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a for loop, you can specify the number of spaces you wish to output using printf

```
printf("%*c", n, ' ');
```

Comment: Note: that won't print 0 spaces on the last line. But if you print the first *digit* on each line like this, you can, with `printf("%*c", n+1, '1');`

Comment: @WeatherVane printf("%*s", spaces, ""); seems to work when spaces is equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

I use 3 loops in my code

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int n=5;
 for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {printf("\n");
       for(int j=n-1;j>=i;j--)
       {
            printf(" ");
       }
       for(int k=i-1;k>=-(i-1);k--)
       {
             printf("%d",i-abs(k));
       }
 }
 printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Can you explain the work of abs() function here

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use only one loop :

Initialize the term to 1
Initialize an IncreaseFactor to 21

At each pass :
Compute num of spaces
Print spaces like pp182 suggested (guard against zero spaces)
Print the term
Print spaces like pp182 suggested (guard against zero spaces)
Multiply Term by 100, and Add the IncreaseFactor to Term
Multiply IncreaseFactor by 10 and add 11

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version which uses just one for loop.

Also it continues the pattern in a decreasing manner.

```
/* diamond.c -- display a palindrome diamond

   e.g. 4 digit diamond

   diamond      numerical value
   -------      ---------------
      1         = 1    squared
     121        = 11   squared
    12321       = 111  squared
   1234321      = 1111 squared
    12321       = 111  squared
     121        = 11   squared
      1         = 1    squared
*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf("\n"
           "palindrome diamond program\n"
           "\n");

    int digits;
    do {
        printf("number of digits (1 to 9): ");
        scanf("%d", &digits);
    } while ((digits < 1) || (digits > 9));
    printf("\n");

    int spaces = digits - 1;
    long long num = 0;
    long long tens = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= digits * 2 - 1; ++i) {
        printf("%*s", spaces, "");
        num += tens;
        printf("%lld\n", num * num);
        (i < digits) ? --spaces : ++spaces;
        tens = (i < digits) ? tens * 10 : (i == digits) ? -tens : tens / 10;
    }

    return 0;
}
```